# push syntax in Javascript for an array within an array

Tags: javascript

```
"elements": [
    {
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 70
            }
        ],
        "dot-style": {
            "dot-size": 2,
            "halo-size": 2,
            "type": "solid-dot"
        },
        "on-show": {
            "type": ""
        },
        "font-size": 15,
        "loop": false,
        "type": "line",
        "tip": "#val#%"
    }
]
```

In the above array example I need to add data to `values` array which is part of `elements` array dynamically. How do I do it using JavaScript push method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you will see, it's much easier to conceptualise your code if it is formatted well. Tools like [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) can help with this task.

First, it's clear that `elements` is part of a JS object. We'll call it `foo`, but you'll  have to change this to the correct name in your code.

```
foo.elements[0].values.push({
    value: 'some value'
});
```

This will add a new object to the `values` array.

Answer (score 3):

```
elements[0].values.push({"value": new_value});
```

Answer (score 1):

if the above is named var obj,

```
obj['elements'][0]['values'].push(someValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming elements is part of an object called `myObj` for the example below, you could use either syntax.

```
myObj["elements"][0]["values"].push({ value: "my new value" });
```

or

```
myObj.elements[0].values.push({ value: "my new value" });
```